# Android studio can not connect to firebase with error Failed to get FIS auth token

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried to connect my app to firebase, but it always gives me this error.
Does that happen because I do not select the Google repository in SDK tools? (since there is no Google repository option in the SDK)

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/172.217.160.106 (port 443) from /10.0.2.16 (port 48742) after 10000ms
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.0:54)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.0:72)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/172.217.160.106 (port 443) from /10.0.2.16 (port 48742) after 10000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:182)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:208)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.writeFIDCreateRequestBodyToOutputStream(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:190)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:160)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:464)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCall(FirebaseInstallations.java:341)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationInternal$0(FirebaseInstallations.java:331)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same issue

Comment: open the vpn solves it